# One Controller for different views?(MVC)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controller

I got an app, which has a homescreen. On this homescreen you can click buttons, which open other views(for music, gallery, video, games etc.). Now I ask myself, if I should use one controller for all of these views or one controller for one view. The music and video views got the same buttons and Hyperlinks.The gallery, games and settings views have all different ui controls. I searched in the internet for an answer, but I can't found anything, when to create a new controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is to use separate controllers. But you don't really have to especially if your pages do not have a lot of functionality on them.